# Which video editor for Linux has the video speed control effect?

Tags: linux, video-editing

I have so far tried Pitivi and Shotcut, but neither of these seem to have this effect, by which one could speed up or slow down certain segments of a video. Also, Shotcut doesn't even work very well on my system and tends to crash at every opportunity. Unfortunately my bandwidth is limited, so I don't have much of a chance to try out many such video editors. If someone knows one such editor for Linux, I would find such answer very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the speed of parts of a video with [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/features/).

However you can only set a specific speed for a specific part so if you want to have it slowly increase or decrease the speed you need to cut the video multiple times (right click->cut) and change it to a different percentage for each fragment.

To change the speed right click the cut part of the video->Change speed. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268689/1072295).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blender, it is packaged on the must known linux distributions.

[features](https://www.blender.org/features/)

[desired feature:](https://www.blender.org/features/video-editing/)

> The Video Editor includes:

> - Live preview, luma waveform, chroma vectorscope and histogram
>   displays.
> - Audio mixing, syncing, scrubbing and waveform visualization.
> - Up to 32 slots for adding video, images, audio, scenes, masks and
>   effects.
> - **Speed control**, adjustment layers, transitions, keyframes, filters and more!

see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/